# Sorting keys in property list in iOS

Tags: ios, sorting, plist

I have created a property list with the keys 1 to 11, all with the value 0.

The list is to be used as datasource for a picker view.

I have these property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *erfaring;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *erfaringKeys;
```

And this in the implementation file:

```
NSString *erfaringFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                         pathForResource:@"Erfaring" ofType:@"plist"];
erfaring = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:erfaringFile];
erfaringKeys = [erfaring allKeys];
```

The problem is, that when the keys are loaded in to the picker view they are sorted wrong like: 7, 3, 8, 4, 11, 9, 5, 1, 6, 2, 10.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sort the keys of the dictionary

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"String 1", @"1",
                     @"String 4", @"4",
                     @"String 3", @"3",
                     @"String 2", @"2", nil];

NSArray *sortedKeys = [dic keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Then iterate using sorted keys

```
for (NSString *sortedKey in sortedKeys) {
    NSString *value = [dic objectForKey:sortedKey];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your array before loading in picker-

```
erfaringKeys = [erfaring allKeys];
erfaringKeys = [erfaringKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it dont work when the keys value are set to "numbers". Setting them to "Strings" sorts them 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: You can check this thread for resolving this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558761/sorting-an-nsarray-of-nsstring